# Regular Expression to pull data between two nodes (including nodes)

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regular expressions to pull a specified line out. Below is how my data is formatted. My function will receive a node name (such as "cat" in this example). What would be the RegEx rule to pull the entire line (including the beginning and ending nodes)?

**Data:**

```
<Bat>Jim;Doug;<Bat>
<Cat>Jake;Dan;Bill;<Cat>
<Dog>Greg;Bob;Ashley;<Dog>
```

**Desired Result:**

```
<Cat>Jake;Dan;Bill;<Cat>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use this: `(<Cat>).*\1`

It will find any line that starts and ends with `Cat`.